# c++ How can i use ANSI escape codes with WriteConsoleOutput?

Tags: c++, console, windows-console, ansi-escape

My buffer:

```
CHAR_INFO *ciScreenBuffer = new CHAR_INFO[bufferWidth * bufferHeight];
```

How can i use ANSI codes like this to colorize my output char ?

```
"\x1b[38;2;R;G;Bm""
```

P.S i use that

```
WriteConsoleOutputA(hConsoleOutput, ciScreenBuffer, { (SHORT)bufferWidth, (SHORT)bufferHeight }, { 0, 0 }, &writeRegion);
```

Comment: Just put those escape sequences to the buffer. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: I cant put escape sequences to my buffer because it contains information only about   character and argument(FOREGROUND_BLUE, BACKGROUND_GREEN etc).

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What prevents you from putting the escape sequence itself?

Comment: ciScreenBuffer[50].Char.AsciiChar = "\x1b[38;2;25;71;150mHello"; Its not working

Comment: Just use WriteConsole instead of WriteConsoleOutput.

Comment: It will down my perfomance a lot. Because i'll use that for drawing moveable sprites

Answer (score 1):

[`WriteConsoleOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput) does not use nor parse ANSI sequences.  You provide the color information as part of the [`CHAR_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/char-info-str) data you pass in.

To add color to your output, update the color member of the `ciScreenBuffer` array when you add the characters you want to display.  For example, based on an example in one of your comments,

```
ciScreenBuffer[50].Attributes = FOREGROUND_BLUE;
```